# soql query error

Tags: soql

```
List<Opportunity_Payment__c> opp = [SELECT Id,(SELECT Owner.Id FROM Opportunity__r) FROM Opportunity_Payment__c];
```

- Opportunity_Payment__c has master-detail relationship field to the opportunity.

> **ERROR:  **Didn't understand relationship 'Opportunity__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom
>   relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom
>   relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for
>   the appropriate names.

Comment: List<Opportunity_Payment__c>***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Opportunity_Payment__c` has a master-detail relationship field(let's call it oppParent) to Opportunity object, it means that you'll have just 1 parent per `Opportunity_Payment__c`, hence your query should be a children to parent query (**`Right Outer Join`**):

```
List<Opportunity_Payment__c> opp = [SELECT Id, oppParent__r.Owner.Id
                                    FROM Opportunity_Payment__c];
```

What you're using in your query is a parent to child relationship query (**`Left Outer Join`**), which would be ok if you run it for opportunity sobject:

```
List<Opportunity> opp = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Opportunity_Payments__r)
                                    FROM Opportunity];
```

More info

- [A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com)
- [Understanding Relationship Names](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding)